# Web Form Styling: use the HTML element "form" or "data"?

Tags: css, html, forms

### How best to structure a Data Entry screen in HTML5?

- Keep in mind I would like to use table-less CSS
- I have *some* data already collected (fileds 1,2,3) and want to collect fields 4 and 5
- I am looking at forms, lists, or data elements - all seem like they could do the job

**Step 1** - Present the data in `{field1,field2,field3}` which has already been collected. 
FYI - the data is brought to page with the following PHP script  and it works - no issues here.

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['field1'],'<br>';
    echo $row['field2'],'<br>';
    echo $row['field3'],'<br>';
}
```

**Step 2** - Show the input fields for new data
I want to show input fields for `{field4,field5}`.

## QUESTION:

Must I use the HTML element "form" or should/can I be using the "data" or "list" HTML element ?

```
<label for="form_id">Test Form</label>
<input type="text" name="field4" value="" />
<label for="form_id">Test Form</label>
<input type="text" name="field5" value="" />
```

Here is a visual representation of the data entry screen.

```
|----------------|
|Filed1: Data1   |
|Filed2: Data2   |
|Filed3: Data3   |
|----------------|   
|Field4: (Empty) |
|Field5: (Empty) |
|----------------|
```

Comment: use a "form"/input elements if you want it to be editable/if you're going to send the data later. use a list/table if you just want to display. data is HTML5, and usually you'll use it to keep data in an element to use with your code, not for display/user interaction.

Comment: thanks! I want a portion of the record to be editable... so I will use "form"/input. I was concerned that this approach would restrict me to tables?

Comment: To begin with, there is no “data” element in HTML5. And whether you “must” use a form element depends on what you are going to do with the input, client-side or server-side, and how. The question is far too vague for constructive answers.